# Plotting many images at once in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org) and  [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org) to do a statistical simulation.  The simulation itself is pretty fast thanks to numPy vectorizatio, however the plotting is slow since I still use a `for` loop.

Here is the result:

[image]

Right now, I call `matplotlib.pyplot.plt` 10000 times - once for each tile in 100 × 100 square which can't possibly be optimal, but I can't think of how to do it better:

```
N = 100
for x in range(N):
    for y in range(N):
        plt.fill( myPath[x,y,0] ,myPath[x,y,1])
```

Let's say I stored all the varaibles in an numPy array `myPath` with shape `(N,N,2,4)` so that `myPath[x,y,0]` and `myPath[x,y,1]` give the x and y coordinates of the path.

How do I reduce the number of calls to `plt` in my visualization?

Comment: Wouldn't `plt.fill(myPath[..., ..., 0], myPath[..., ..., 1])` without a loop do the trick?

Answer (score 4):

Try using matplotlib's `LineCollection` class. [Here's an example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/line_collection2.html).

In your case, you might do:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

ax = plt.gca()
pts = myPath.reshape((-1,2))  # make a matrix of (x,y) pairs
edges = LineCollection(pts)
ax.add_collection(edges)
plt.show()
```